# just making the query in parent component and not rendering anything and sending all data as props

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I want to make one query in my parent component and not render anything and pass that data onto some child component .
How can we achieve this in react and graphql ?

```
               {
                   ({loading,error,data}) =>{
                     if(loading) return <h4>Loading...</h4>
                       if(error) console.log(error)
                       console.log("graphql data is ",data);

                       return(
                       <div className="body">
                                  </div>


                               </div>


                       );
                 }
               }

              </Query>
```

I want to make this query in my parent component and pass it as child components .
In case of simple apis ,I could simply call the api and store it in my redux and then get those data as props in child .
How can same be achieved without rendering anything ?

Comment: While there's any number of ways to fetch data outside of the `Query` component, it's unclear why you would need to do so. If the data is only needed by the child component, and not the parent, then wrap the child component with the Query component. Even if you have multiple children, you can safely reuse the same Query component for each one without triggering multiple network requests.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this or are you still looking for a solution.

Comment: No .I couldn't .Still looking for any hints due to limited knowledge on apollo and state management in apollo .

Comment: I think I have a work around for this in react. I have posted the answer below. Let me know if works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component just to render its children. Here is an example how to do it in react.

Something like this.

```
class Query extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    error: {},
    data: {}
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //do the apicall here
    this.setState({ loading: false, data: { header: "may the force be with you" } });
  }

  render() {
    const { state: props, props: { children } } = this;

    // return the data here
    // passing state as props here after renaming state to props
    return children(props);
  }
}
```

Using react state instead of redux. You can make this connected component if you want to use redux. And the use the component like this.

```
    <Query>
      {
        ({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return <>Loading.......</>
          if (Object.keys(error).length > 0) return <>Some Error Handler</>
          if (data) return (
            <>
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <a
                className="App-link"
                href="https://reactjs.org"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                {data.header}
              </a>
            </>
          )
        }
      }
    </Query>
```